# Android WiFi router

Tags: android, open-source, wifi

I am looking for an app to share my Android phone's Internet connection to my computers.

Requirements:

- Open source
- Secure WiFi protocol
- Visible icon when running
- 1x1 widget to easily start/stop

Comment: What's the OS for the computers?

Comment: @rrirower: Any computer OS should be able to use the created WiFi.

Comment: Are you taking about setting up your phone as a hotspot?  If so, android already has that capability.

Comment: @rrirower: Could you please add this as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android provides the native ability to create a WiFi hotspot.  On my phone, running 4.4.2, it's under "Mobile Hotspot".  *Mobile Hotspot* allows you to define the mac address of the "allowed devices" that can connect to the hotspot.  To simplify things, there's also a one touch widget in the app store that will allow the enabling/disabling of the hotspot.  The widget I use is called *WiFi HotSpot*.

Comment: To make it even simpler, there's an hotspot shortcut in the notifications area :) And, to meet the OP's requirements, afaik also a notification icon in the notification bar when the hotspot is active (I've not checked that one, though). Also worth mentioning: You can of course also configure the SSID – but AFAIK you cannot easily define the IP addresses to be used by the hotspot. The hotspot feature IMHO has been added with ICS or earlier (I cannot currently check, but it's there at least with 4.1).

Comment: @Izzy I can confirm the existence of a notification icon with Android 5.0.1.

Comment: And I have to correct myself: Hotspot was introduced with [Android 2.2](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.2-highlights.html) (Froyo) already...